# Showing checked checkbox from database for editing

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am trying to show the checked checkboxes from database which are added during inserting user.But when I am editing that user I want to show those checkboxes as checked.How to do that.Here is my code for edit.

```
$edit = true;
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

$userEdit = $executeQuery->oneRowCondition("user_master", "user_id='$id'");

if(isset($_REQUEST['subMitBtn'])){

    @$username = $_REQUEST['user_name'];
    @$compID = $_REQUEST['compID'];
    @$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    @$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
    @$q1=explode(',',$_POST['q1']);

    @$q2=$q1.",";


    $insertUser = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user_master SET 
         user_name = '$username', user_email='$email', user_password='$password',user_module='$q2' where  user_id = '$compID' ");
    echo "UPDATE user_master SET 
         user_name = '$username', user_email='$email', user_password='$password',user_module='$q2' where  user_id = '$compID' ";     


}
```

And HTML code is:

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Modules</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Dashboard" > Dashboard<br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Order Entry"> Order Entry <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Status"> Status <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Customers"> Customers <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Shipping Company" > Shipping Company <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Shipping Rates" > Shipping Rates <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Retailer"> Retailer <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Marketing"> Marketing <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Sales Report"> Sales Report <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Inward Report"> Inward Report <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Outward Report"> Outward Report <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Users & Roles"> Users & Roles <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Change Password"> Change Password <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Email Settings"> Email Settings <br>
```

Comment: Are you sure `@$q1=explode(',',$_POST['q1']);` is correct? Don't you want to do `implode()`?

Comment: But to address your question. It looks like you are saving your checkboxes as a csv. You will need to do an `explode()` and then you could use `in_array()` on each value to see if it is in the array, and if so set it to checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this statement, `@$q1=explode(',',$_POST['q1']);` is incorrect. I'm pretty sure you're trying to do `implode` here to get a string representation of array. It should be `q1 = implode(',', $_POST['q1'])`.

Second, your question,

> when I am editing that user I want to show those checkboxes as checked

Get all the checkbox values from the database, like this:

```
$result_set = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_module FROM user_master WHERE user_id = '$compID'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
$checkbox_array = explode(",", $result['user_module']);
```

And your HTML should be like this:

```
// your code

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Dashboard"<?php if(in_array("Dashboard", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Dashboard<br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Order Entry"<?php if(in_array("Order Entry", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Order Entry <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Status"<?php if(in_array("Status", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Status <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Customers"<?php if(in_array("Customers", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Customers <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Shipping Company"<?php if(in_array("Shipping Company", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Shipping Company <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Shipping Rates"<?php if(in_array("Shipping Rates", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Shipping Rates <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Retailer"<?php if(in_array("Retailer", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Retailer <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Marketing"<?php if(in_array("Marketing", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Marketing <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Sales Report"<?php if(in_array("Sales Report", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Sales Report <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Inward Report"<?php if(in_array("Inward Report", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Inward Report <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Outward Report"<?php if(in_array("Outward Report", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Outward Report <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Users & Roles"<?php if(in_array("Users & Roles", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Users & Roles <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Change Password"<?php if(in_array("Change Password", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Change Password <br />

<input type="checkbox" id="q1[]" name="q1[]" value="Email Settings"<?php if(in_array("Email Settings", $checkbox_array)){ echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Email Settings <br />

// your code
```

Comment: Thank You this helped me to do.

Comment: @sneha Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you can do this but the basic prinicple of one way is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" value="Inward Report"
<?php if($mycheckbox==true) echo " checked "?>
>
```